# Como mostrar ciertas imagenes en PHP?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

tengo un detalle en mi sistema a la hora de dar de alta un producto con imagenes, en muchos productos solo tengo 1 imagen, pero en algunos tengo mas de 1 para insertar. Pero cuando solo inserto 1 se ve asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui es donde mando a llamar la información de mi base de datos

```
<?php
        $pid = $_GET['pid'];
        $select_products = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE id = ?"); 
        $select_products->execute([$pid]);
        if($select_products->rowCount() > 0){
        while($fetch_product = $select_products->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    ?>
```

Aqui es donde inserto para ver las imagenes en un div.

```
<div class="image-container">
            <div class="big-image">
                <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $fetch_product['image_01']; ?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="small-images">
                <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $fetch_product['image_01']; ?>" alt="">
                
                <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $fetch_product['image_02']; ?>" alt="">
                <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $fetch_product['image_03']; ?>" alt=""> 
            </div>
        </div>
```

Como podría que no se muestren esas dos cuando no haya imagenes insertadas cuando se dio de alta el producto.

Comment: Aquí el problema de base está en el diseño de tu modelo de datos. Deberías tener una tabla asociativa donde guardarás la relación de productos e imágenes. Esa tabla tendría dos columnas: `imagenID, productoID`, puede tener también otra columna que identifique el tipo de imagen (principal, grande, pequeña, mediana, etc). Diseñando así, tendrás siempre exactamente las imágenes que se relacionan con cada producto, sea 1, sean 5, sean 10,000 imágenes. Si no resuelves tu problema a nivel de diseño, tendrás que pasarte la vida resolviendo ese problema a otro nivel, pegando parches.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que el campo de la imagen no este vacio antes de pintar la `img`

```
<?php if(strlen($fetch_product['image_01']) > 0 ){ ?>
  <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $fetch_product['image_01']; ?>" alt="">
<?php}?>   

<?php if(strlen($fetch_product['image_02']) > 0 ){ ?>
  <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $fetch_product['image_02']; ?>" alt="">
 <?php}?>  
 
 <?php if(strlen($fetch_product['image_03']) > 0 ){ ?>
   <img src="uploaded_img/<?= $fetch_product['image_03']; ?>" alt=""> 
 <?php}?>
```